# Network Drive setup

Tags: windows, windows-registry, network-drive

I have been trying to setup network drive on Windows 8.1 for a Box account.
Initially it didn't connect so followed these steps here.

https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/entries/21587905-Error-message-0x80070043-the-network-name-cannot-be-found-while-setting-up-Mapped-drive-Prompt-for-U

As soon as i enter the registry values(WDNP32,SnacNp,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient) the box account gets connected.

But the problem is the registry values gets reverted back to original after a restart.

Why registry is not saving these values? How do i save it permanently?

Thanks!!!

Comment: A Box account?

Why not use a logon script with net use?

Comment: @AthomSfere sorry but I don't know what is a logon script. I'm trying to setup a network drive just because the upload via site is too slow.Whereas network drive does so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a logon script instead of manually messing with the registry.

To do a user profile script:

open:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

1. Right click, and create a new text file.
2. Edit the text file to include your mapped drive information.

For example, to map a drive letter M with the current Windows account

```
net use M: \\serverName\ShareName
```

If you need to use alternate credentials on the share, use the following format:

```
net use M: \\ServerName\ShareName /user:UserName yourPassword
```

3. Save
4. Rename the text file to "WhateveryouWant.bat" Make sure the new extension is `.bat`

Comment: Is this format correct? net use I:https://dav.box.com/dav/user:James 12345

Comment: There is a space between the i: and the server, and the server and the /user switch but yes. `net use I: dav.box.com/dav /user:James 12345`

Comment: Well it didn't work.Thanks anyways

Comment: What did it do? Call it from the command prompt and give me the errors, better yet append the errors to your post.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.It says "System error 67 has occurred"       "The network name cannot be found" And the entry is the format you told  "net use I: https://dav.box.com/dav /user:someone@gmail.com passphrase"

Comment: Ah, I see whats going on. An https "box"... you kight look at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97c16139-1851-4623-80e4-5fe37d7a984b/windows-7-authenticated-webdav-over-https?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: Is there any other solution for this?